# An object exposed to directives that need to track changes on it

Tags: javascript, angular.js

This is an object exposed to the view and is being used on directives within the same view. The directives need to track changes on the `ctrl.filters.applied` object. It's a simple part of a project at my work and I'd like to know if I'm doing it right.

Other properties and methods are just being used on the view itself.

`ctrl` is the controller, since I'm using `controllerAs` syntax.

```
var ctrl = this;
```

Filters object:

```js
ctrl.filters = (function filters() {

    var currentFilters,
        appliedFilters,
        initialFilters = {
            companies: [],
            user: null,
            workDate: {
                initial: null,
                final: null
            }
        };

    currentFilters = angular.copy(initialFilters);
    appliedFilters = angular.copy(currentFilters);

    function apply() {
        appliedFilters = angular.copy(currentFilters);
    };
    function clear() {
        currentFilters = angular.copy(initialFilters);
        appliedFilters = angular.copy(currentFilters);
    };

    return function filtersReturn() {
        return {
            current: currentFilters,
            applied: appliedFilters,
            apply: apply,
            clear: clear
        };
    };

})();
```

Directive example:

```html
<wkp-my-directive 
    wkp-filters="ctrl.filters().applied">
</wkp-my-directive>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the problem you are trying to solve with this code? I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @DanPantry I've edited the question to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> return function filtersReturn() {
>     return {
>         current: currentFilters,
>         applied: appliedFilters,
>         apply: apply,
>         clear: clear
>     };
> };
> ```

This piece of code looks odd to me,  could you simply return the object itself, like this:

```
var returnFilters = {
    current: currentFilters,
    applied: appliedFilters,
    apply: apply,
    clear: clear
;}  
return returnFilters;
```

I just don't see the point of returning a function that doesn't do "*function*" stuff,  it really returns a function that returns an object, so why not just return the object to begin with?

One more thing, I didn't like the name of the function, so when I changed it to an object I changed the naming as well.  The name `returnFilters` sounds better than `filtersReturn`  I mean when I say "filters return"  I am thinking "filters return ... what?"  but these are **the return filters** so I want the name to express that for me so when I read the code later I don't get confused as to what this filter is doing.